# Is there a way to inject JavaScript automatically from chrome dev tool after refreshing the page?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, refresh

I write some JavaScripts into chrome console. Meta tag which I show you below allow to browser refresh in 5 seconds. I want to inject the same code **automatically** after my page is reloaded. Because dev console injected JavaScripts are gone when you refresh the page. Could I do that right in the chrome dev tool?

Thank you

```
var meta = document.createElement('meta');
meta.httpEquiv = "refresh";
meta.content = "5";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);
```

Comment: You can write a chrome extension for same which will inject code on every load

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot directly write code in the chrome console and make it persist between page reloads, however you can use the [Local Overrides](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/01/devtools#overrides) in DevTools introduced in Chrome 65.

First, you will need to enable local overrides in the Sources tab of DevTools. Then select a folder to save the overrides and give the permission to access that folder. After that, you can search for a file and add your code. See image below.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I already know the overrides feature of the chrome dev tool. That will definitely solve my problem. As you said, I can not persists code which is written through the console.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to refresh the page every 5 seconds, you can use this [extensions](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/auto-refresh/ifooldnmmcmlbdennkpdnlnbgbmfalko?hl=fr)

Comment: Thank you for the reply but no I want to make something different